# Fetching data from mysql in node js not working as expected

Tags: mysql, node.js, for-loop, callback

im new to node js. im having a section where i should get all players wrt their teams.

here is the code

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var thenJade = require('then-jade');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'nodejs'
});

exports.players_list = function(req, res) {

    var data = {title: "", res: {}};
        if (authenticate(req, res)) {

            results_aaa(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                res.render('players/players', {title: 'Players List', res: result});
           });

        } else {
            req.session.error = 'Please login to continue.';
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
};

function results_aaa(callback) {
    teams(function(res) {
        callback(res)
    });
}

function teams(callback) {
    var response = [];
    var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
        for (var index in result)
        {
            players(result[index].id, function(results) {
                callback(result);
            });

        }
    });
}

function players(id, callback) {
    query("SELECT * FROM players where team = " + id, function(results) {
        callback(results);
    });
}

function query(sql, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
        callback(results);
    });
}
```

but im getting the players from only one team. As node js is async, its returning one team players and loading the view.

This is the console output for the above code.

```
Express server listening on port 8081
[ { id: 2, player_name: 'Virat Kohli', team: '1' },
  { id: 4, player_name: 'A B DeVilliers', team: '1' },
  { id: 6, player_name: 'Chris Gayle', team: '1' } ]
GET /players 200 89ms - 638
[ { id: 7, player_name: 'Ajinkya Rahane', team: '2' },
  { id: 8, player_name: 'Shane Watson', team: '2' },
  { id: 9, player_name: 'Stuart Binny', team: '2' },
  { id: 10, player_name: 'Karun Nair', team: '2' },
  { id: 11, player_name: 'Sanju Samson', team: '2' } ]
[ { id: 1, player_name: 'Virender Sehwag', team: '3' },
  { id: 3, player_name: 'David Miller', team: '3' },
  { id: 5, player_name: 'Shaun Marsh', team: '3' } ]
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 304 22ms
GET /css/style.css 304 6ms
GET /js/bootstrap.js 304 4ms
GET /js/bootstrap.min.js 304 4ms
GET /css/bootstrap.css 200 32ms - 129.44kb
```

Im struk here, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the issue in my code. I have to use async in teams() function to get complete data
    function teams(callback) {
        var response = [];
        var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
            var tasks = [];
        result.forEach(function(team) {
            response.push(function(callback1) {
                players(team.id, callback1);
            });
        });
        async.parallel(response, function(error, response) {
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the 'teams' function. callback(result) is being called inside of the 'for' loop. Basically, you are rendering the page on each iteration. Try placing callback(result); outside of the loop and adding each team to the response.

```
function teams(callback) {
var response = [];
var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
    for (var index in result)
    {
        players(result[index].id, function(results) {
            callback(result);
        });

    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried like this, but not working
    function teams(callback) {
        var response = [];
        var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
        var response = [];
        for (var index in result)
        {
            players(result[index].id, function(results) {
                response.push(results);
            });
        }        
        callback(response);        
    });
}

Comment: Could you upload your work to github/jsfiddle. It'll be easier for others to help. Also, if it is not working, can you please post the errors associated with it? What exactly is not working? You need to be more specific. Link for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If i console.log(response) in teams function i'm getting empty array.